# how do complete a hover effect to show image that do not limited to the table as show in demo site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do use jquery or other way to complete a hover effect to show image that do not limited to the table and can above it as show in pictures? As shown in the demo site,

```
 ([a link]http://23.23.218.31:8080/PheniBQ/project/id/4)
```

If you click the "List of Variables in this project (11 entries found.)" and hover to each line of the table,  the image will show above the table.

I have complete the table in the html and have the images in the server. But don't know how to show the images.

My html code:

```
   <tr data-depth="0" class="expand" style="line-height:30px;">
        <td style="text-indent: 1em;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;cursor:pointer"><span class="toggle collapse"> List of Variables in this project (${vcount} entries found.) </span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-depth="1" class="expand level1" style="display:none; ">
        <td style="text-indent: 0.5em;width:3400px;"><span class="collapse level1">  
        <div id="demo">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table3" class="display">          
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ><h3>#</h3></th>
                        <th ><h3>Variable Name</h3></th>
                        <th ><h3>Method description</h3></th>
                        <th ><h3>Scale</h3></th>
                    </tr>
                <thead>
                <tbody>
                    % for vitem in vsearch:
                        <tr>
                            <td >${vitem['vcount']}</td>
                            <td ><dl class="collapse" >
                                     <dt >${vitem['vname']}&emsp;<img src="${request.static_url('phenibq_p:static/images/Chart_Bar.png')}" mce_src="image.jpg" width="30" height="30"></dt>
                                     <dd style="display:none"><img src="${request.static_url('phenibq_p:static/images/'+vitem['picfile'])}"></dd>
                                </dl>
                            </td>
                            <td >${vitem['mdes']}</td>
                            <td >${vitem['scalename']}</td>
                        </tr>
                    % endfor
               </tbody>
           </table> 
        </div>

       </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I want to show vitem['picfile'] (dd) when the mouse hover to Chart_Bar.png (dt). And the shown images should not be limited to the table. THX~

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code that you're having trouble with? That would help.

Comment: You mean my html code?